# Let's burn the [mouseless] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

While scrolling through tags aimlessly (yes i'm that bored) i came across the [mouseless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mouseless) tag. This tag has no wiki, and has only been used 5 times... All by the same user. I say we burn it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It has been done. Didn't seem to be adding any value.